# html5-qrcode webpack encore

Tags: symfony, webpack, qr-code, webpack-encore

I try use https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode
with webpack

```
 npm i html5-qrcode --save


+ html5-qrcode@2.0.11
added 2 packages from 2 contributors in 8.99s
root@21ce69a5652
```

/application# yarn run encore dev --watch

in js file

```
import("html5-qrcode");
```

compilation success but give console error

```
ncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'Html5Qrcode' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (html5-qrcode.min.js:6)
    at Object../node_modules/html5-qrcode/dist/html5-qrcode.min.js (html5-qrcode.min.js:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at __webpack_require__.t (bootstrap:182)


require('html5-qrcode');
```

like import but error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Html5Qrcode' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (html5-qrcode.min.js:6)
    at Object../node_modules/html5-qrcode/dist/html5-qrcode.min.js (html5-qrcode.min.js:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../assets/components/ScannerQrCode.js (ScannerQrCode.js:6)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../assets/components/Games.js (app.js:374)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../assets/components/Home.js (app.js:748)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
    at Module../assets/app.js (app.js:1)
```

Comment: Can you try using yarn to install instead of npm ? `yarn add html5-qrcode` and then `yarn install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Author here) This has been fixed in latest release `2.1.0`

- Github release: [mebjas/html5-qrcode/releases/tag/v2.1.0](https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode/releases/tag/v2.1.0)
- [npm - html5-qrcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html5-qrcode)

Please let me know if this solves the issue, else let me know or file a issue on the GitHub project directly - [mebjas/html5-qrcode](https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode/issues)